# Am I so predictable?

Tags: translation, equivalent-phrase

When I go to my favorite restaurant, I often order the same thing. I order in Chinese and apparently I've become predictable. How can I ask an equivalent (not necessarily equal) phrase of "am I so predictable?"

Google translate gives a literal translation that may sound awkward (I'm not sure).

難道我的預測？

Is there a set-phrase that is often used to express this idea?

Comment: In general X-able is translated as 可X. One can thus say `我就这么可/好预测吗?` for `am I so predictable?`, which is grammatical correct but still sounds very non-native. Some native ways to say this are, I suppose, `我要点什么就这么好猜/有规律吗?`, `所以你又知道我要点什么了吗?`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answers covered the translation part. I am going to give my two cents on the culture side.

> Is there a set-phrase that is often used to express this idea?

I don't think so, because traditionally Chinese don't really respond that way. If someone is 'predicting' your order, he's really saying 'I know what you like' as a gesture of intimacy, friendliness or at least, care. A positive response is usually along the line with 'exactly', 'you really know me', 'it's a pleasant surprise that you remembered', etc. I am not quite sure what subtext does 'am I so predictable' convey in English speaking culture, but a verbatim translation in Chinese doesn't sound very positive when used as a response to that 'predicting' conversation. Considering how uniformity, agreement and tacit understanding were valued in traditional Chinese culture, 'am I so predictable' might sound fun or sexy to some listeners, but it might be perceived as rejection, a perverse personality or a bad mood to some other listeners, depending on their social role and culture belief. I am not saying you shouldn't respond that way, just a reminder of how it could be received differently from your intention.

Some simple, low-key positive acknowledgements:

- 没错 (exactly)
- 你猜对了 (your guess is right)
- 你都记住了 (you remembered!)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of insight I need. Can you provide a positive response that works in this case; such as "you really know me..." (would that be 真的了解我?) -- The context is what makes this my most valuable answer.

Comment: @TommieC. You can say something as simple as '没错', '你猜对了'. I am still not sure what you want to express though - just a positive acknowledgement or do you want to lead the conversation into something?

Comment: I'd like to have a fairly low-key positive response where I just acknowledge the fact that they remember me. There is no particular direction after that. The other person might come away with the fact that I find it a bit amusing.

Comment: @TommieC. Got it. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 我點的菜真的是經常一樣嗎？ It means "Am I always ordering the same thing?".

The Google Translate one translated back to English means "Really, my predictions?".

Comment: another suggestion:我点什么菜如此预料之中？

Answer (score 1):

我就這麼好猜嗎？ (Am I so predictable?)

我有這麼好猜嗎？ (Have I so predictable?)

難道我的預測？   (Maybe my forecast?)

--

We always put 真的 and 是 together, but there's no really answer,

it's just an habit(?), so it should be 我點的菜"真的是"經常一樣嗎？

Comment: The third one is from Google Translator as the OP said, and it is not correct